# Is it possible to set a global uncaught exception handler in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'd like to catch uncaught exceptions in Meteor and handle them in a graceful fashion.  Is there an analogue to Node's `process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {})`?

I'm interested in solutions both in the client and in the server.

Comment: this would be nice if it exists, i'm using `window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {...};` on the client side for now

Comment: I'm trying to figure out this stuff too for the server. However, it seems as if Meteor at least catches exceptions from server methods, and reports them itself :(

Answer (score 1):

I am testing this idea for server side uncaught exception handling.

```
Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
    console.log(err.message);
    console.log(err.stack);
    Fiber( function(){
        Logs.insert({ ... }) // Logs is a collection
    }).run();
    process.exit(1)
};
```

Comment: Does this even work? I tried installing an `uncaughtException` handler, but it doesn't fire. Seems as if Meteor is overriding this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well, ended up overriding the different console methods, as I can live without stacktraces. Errors are displayed in the console window, so this does the trick for me. process.on('uncaughtException', ...) doesn't work with Meteor, and for some strange reason they don't provide any nice alternative.

[This little library](https://github.com/acemtp/meteor-logentries) helped me out a great deal, use it or try looking at the source code - its very short and to the point.